# ssh proxy command with netcat

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, encryption

In example like this:

```
Host destination
  ProxyCommand ssh gateway nc %h %p
```

Is the connection between the gateway and the destination encrypted? I am confused because I have 2 hypotheses and both are not convincing:

1. It's not encrypted. The stdin in source goes through the source-gateway ssh connection encrypted, and get decrypted before being passed to nc, i.e nc's stdin is the same as stdin into ssh client at source. But I think the %p is 22, the ssh port -- which doesn't fit with this hypothesis.
2. It's encrypted, the sshd daemon at gateway pass to nc encrypted data. Then say instead of executing nc, we are executing "cat", does sshd daemon pass it the encrypted data too? That doesn't sound right either.

Comment: Please don't crosspost http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661959/ssh-proxy-command-with-netcat/31662666#31662666

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is encrypted! Just to understand well what is going on here:

```
[ client $ ssh destination ]
  |
  '-> [ gateway $ nc destination 22 ]
        |
        '-> [ destination $ whatever]
```

On client you run just `ssh destination`. This is translated into `ssh gateway nc destination 22`.

So first executed command is `ssh gateway` with command. We have encrypted first step for sure.

The `nc destination 22` command is run in this session on `gateway` server. And it does basically the thing that it redirects all I/O to the `destination` host, just as it is (but we are already in encrypted channel!).

So you will do once more key exchange with and authentication with `destination` and after it will succeed, you will get probably shell prompt there. So it is again encrypted.